# How should I represent tasks and sub-tasks in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to decide on a good data model for representing tasks and sub-tasks. It's a two part problem:

First, I want to be able to get a string of tasks (task1)-[:NEXT]->(task2)-[:NEXT]->(task3) etc. And I want to be able to gather them starting with the first one and display them in order. The cypher is simple enough ... something like

```
p = match(first:Task)-[:NEXT*]->(others:Task)
return o.name, o.instructions
order by length(p) // or something like this, probably with a union to get both the first task and other tasks in the same output
```

However, I'd also like to let a sub-task have children. For instance, I might have a set of tasks that constitute "How to make coffee", but then when I'm creating a set of tasks that constitute "How to make breakfast", I'd like to point to the "How to make coffee" set of tasks and re-use them.

It would be nice to get cypher to return a staggered list (e.g. 1, 1.1, 1.1.1, 2, etc.), but I'd actually be equally happy with just 1, 2, 3 ... n.

I've been looking and haven't seen a clear solution anywhere. Here's a picture of what I'm imagining. Any directions, thoughts, or references much appreciated.

[image: Tasks numbered kind of how I'd like to be able to retrieve them]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reuse my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50278610/6893866) to another question, but it really is the best solution to this problem. The problem you have is that your scheme starts to fall apart once you have multiple distinct but intersecting paths. So you end up trying to corrupt your data to try and resolve the conflicts generated.

1) For each chain, create a node to represent that chain.

2) Create a relation from that node to each node in the chain, and add an index property on the relationship.

3) Run Cyphers on your "chain" nodes instead.

To expand on the above for your case...

In this instance, the chain node represents a list of tasks that have to be done in order; And can itself also be a task. Separating the list from the task is more work, but it would allow you to define multiple ways to complete a certain task. For example, I can make coffee by starting my coffee machine, asking Google to make it (which will start the machine), or go to Starbucks. This should be flexible enough to support anything you need to represent, without instances trampling on each-other. Part of the key here is relationships can have properties too! Don't be afraid to use that to make them distinct. (You could just add a 'group-id' to each task chain to make them distinct, but that will have scaling issues)

Comment: I'd thought about that, and I agree it's got a lot going for it. The problem is that it makes each chain sort of "historical" inasmuch as it won't change in response to changes of sub-processes. E.g. if the "Submit travel expenses" procedure includes the "Upload expenses" procedure, and that procedure used to include a "Set up your expenses system account", but now that's done at onboarding, when you remove it from the "Upload expenses" procedure, you risk leaving it in any parent procedures. If I'm wrong, please let me know how. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Daniel This is why each task chain only includes the highest abstraction of a task. Each of those tasks are responsible for how they can be done (refer to my make coffee example). Restating this in terms of friends. If Bob is your friend and you are mine, Bob would be my friend by proxy. If you decide you never want to see Bob again, he would no longer be my friend because he is no longer your friend. Another way to look at it is each task list is a workflow, that contains other workflows. If a task can't be broken down any further, than it is a step/task.